# How to debug "Call to a member function dirty() on a non-object" in Cakephp 3.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to do save the data, I got from form.

My error message:

> Error: Call to a member function dirty() on a non-object.

My view code:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($album,['role' => 'form','type' => 'file'])?>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <?= $this->Form->input( 'albumName',
                                                        [   'class' => 'form-control',
                                                            'label' => __('Albüm Adı:'),
                                                            'placeholder' => __('Albüm Adı'),
                                                            'onkeyup' => 'javascript:setVirtualSanalUrl(this,"virtualUrl")']);?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <?= $this->Form->input( 'albumVirtualUrl',
                                                        [   'class' => 'form-control',
                                                            'label' => __('Albüm Sanal Adres(Site Adres Bilgisi İçin):'),
                                                            'placeholder' => __('Albüm Sanal Adres'),
                                                            'id' => 'virtualUrl',
                                                            'onChange' => 'javascript:setVirtualSanalUrl(this,"virtualUrl")']);?>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                            foreach ($Languages as $lang):?>
                            <?php echo $lang;?>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <?= $this->Form->input( '_translations.'.$lang.'.albumName',
                                                            [   'class' => 'form-control',
                                                                'label' => __('Albüm Adı({0}):', [$lang]),
                                                                'placeholder' => __('Albüm Adı({0})', [$lang]),
                                                                'onkeyup' => 'javascript:setVirtualSanalUrl(this,"virtualUrl'.$lang.'")']);?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <?= $this->Form->input( '_translations.'.$lang.'.albumVirtualUrl',
                                                            [   'class' => 'form-control',
                                                                'label' => __('Albüm Sanal Adres(Site Adres Bilgisi İçin)({0}):', [$lang]),
                                                                'placeholder' => __('Albüm Sanal Adres({0})', [$lang]),
                                                                'id' => 'virtualUrl'.$lang,
                                                                'onChange' => 'javascript:setVirtualSanalUrl(this,"virtualUrl'.$lang.'")']);?>
                                </div>
                            <?php
                            endforeach;
                            ?>
                            <div class="box-footer">
                            <?= $this->Form->button(isset($album->id) == false ? __('Kaydet'):__('Düzenle'),
                                                    ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);?>
                        <?= $this->Form->end();?>
```

Data is records that I place:

```
$album = $this->ImageAlbums->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $album = $this->ImageAlbums->patchEntity($album, $this->request->data);
            $album->albumVirtualUrl = $this->createVirtaulUrl($album->albumVirtualUrl);
            if (empty($album->errors())) {
                $resultAlbum = $this->ImageAlbums->save($album);}}
```

This code is not working, but the one below work fine.

```
$example = $this->ImageAlbums->newEntity();
$example->albumName = "deneme";
$example->albumVirtualUrl = "sdsd";
$example->translation('en-US')->albumName = 'albumName';
$example->translation('en-US')->albumVirtualUrl = "albumVirtualUrl";
$example->translation('fr_FR')->albumName = "fr albumName";
$example->translation('fr_FR')->albumVirtualUrl = "fr albumVirtualUrl";
$this->ImageAlbums->save($example);
```

I looked at those pages: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html

I did the steps. You can record data straight but I can not register out of the forum.

Comment: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/4902**

Comment: My error message : Error: Call to a member function dirty() on a non-object. Do you think the solution here ?

Comment: it does not automatically detect it. :S

Comment: Did you read the linked issue? The `_translations` key functionality doesn't exist yet! For now you must use the traits `translation()` method.

Comment: Yes i am read. Thanks :) i am use translation method.

Comment: Judging by the above comment conversation, I think this can be closed because it is a "problem that can no longer be reproduced".

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm a year too late but I was facing the same issue. The dirty() method expect an object, not an array.
So you've to assign the translation manually like you did.
This script should fix the problem :

```
foreach ($this->request->data['_translations'] as $k => $data) {
     foreach ($data as $dataKey => $datum) {
          $yourEntity->translation($k)->{$dataKey} = $datum;
     }
}
$this->Model->save($yourEntity);
```